# Владелец и атрибуты на загружаемые файлы

Tags: php, linux, apache

Привет всем!

Установил ubuntu 14. Установил nginx + apache + php.

Выгрузил файлы сайта от имени пользователя sergey:www-data. Но при загрузке картинки через php скрипт в папку upload файл создается от имени www-data:www-data.

Вопрос, как сделать чтобы файлы создавались от имени sergey:www-data.

Нужно чтобы это было глобальное решение для всех моих сайтов

Comment: При появлении таких вопросов всегда возникает встречный вопрос: "Зачем Вам это нужно? Чего Вы хотите этим достичь?". Часто такого рода проблемы решаются другими методами.

Answer (score 2):

Запустите web-сервер от имени `sergey`. Для apache не знаю, а вот для php-fpm можно создавать отдельный пул для каждого сайта, запущенный от имени пользователя - владельца сайта.

Answer (score 2):

Подобного рода вопросы начинают возникать, когда из linux-сервера начинают делать веб-сервер.

"Простой случай" как раз описан вами: у вас есть пользователь sergey, который (скажем, по ftp) правит файлы сайта. Вам кстати предложили вариант в лоб -- запустить веб-сервер от имени sergey (см. в httpd.conf строки `User apache` и `Group apache` в centos, у вас вместо apache значит www-data), это сработает, но это не best practice. Во-первых, это понижает безопасность сервера. Во-вторых, сайтов может быть несколько -- тогда начинаются попытки для каждого сайта указать "своего Сергея" (смотрим в сторону apache  suexec), в-третьих, бывают случаи посложнее:

"Сложный случай", когда у вас есть целый отдел из пятнадцати людей и у каждого сотрудника есть свой логин, например ivanov и petrov -- как вы понимаете, ваше чувство прекрасного, когда файлы должны на www-data записываться, будет страдать, но вы уже не сможете воспользоваться прежним советом (пользователей-то десятки).

Что делать?

Наиболее хорошая рекомендация, которую я знаю -- это вообще не заливать файлы по ftp. Используйте git для раскатывания кода на продакшн. Пусть десятки сотрудников что-то коммитят, выкладка на сервере осуществляется либо руками, либо постхуком, либо из систем CI (Continious Integration).

Другой способ -- переопределить стандарные для веб-хостингов права на файлы и папки (644 для файлов и 755 для папок) так, чтобы пользователи входящие в группу webmasterz могли править файлы сайта. Способ тоже рабочий, но есть риски.

Бывают движки сайтов, в которых предусмотрены проверки безопасности сайта и они ругаются на всё, что не 644/755; также вы будете часто наталкиваться на статьи в интернете, где новичков которые бездумно ставят 777 на всё подряд пугают дырками (и правильно пугают, кстати!) и тут же не менее бездумно повторяют чужие мантры про рекомендуемые 644/755).

Answer (score 0):

Просто внесите usera sergey в группу `www-data`

`sudo passwd` - установите пароль для root если вдруг где то ошиблись что бы можно было внести группы для юзера, если у вас есть уже root не через судо то можно не делать

`useradd -G www-data sergey` - добавьте юзера в группу

`su` - на всякий случай авторизоваться как root

Comment: пользователь sergey уже был ранее внесен в группу www-data

Comment: @15828 он и сейчас там

Comment: да я сразу создавал 
useradd -g www-data -s /bin/bash sergey

Comment: @15828 и не скромный вопрос а зачем вам владелец именно sergey тогда?

Comment: чтобы путаницы небыло, мне так удобнее. Все файлы сайта от одного владельца - sergey который входит в группу www-data.

Comment: @15828 смотрите ответ выше но это не очень хорошая идея запускать все сайты от одного пользователя который имее bash окружение.