# Как поменять права ftp через ssh putty?

Tags: linux, ftp, права, vds

Ну собственно нужно поменять права всех папок и файлов на сервере или же определенной, нужно менять при добавлении нового пользователя в ftp или как то по другому?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас достаточно прав, то делается это командами:

А) Папки:

```
sudo find /home/user/myfolder -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
```

Б) Файлы:

```
sudo find /home/user/myfolder -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

Маски файлов приведены стандартные.

Вторая часть вопроса - про доступ по ftp сильно зависит от того, как вы настраиваете ftp сервер, я [как-то описывал несколько типовых случаев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541918/%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B/542426#542426), возможно будет полезно.

Comment: Блин я добавил эту строку. sudo find / -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \; И все слетело. Даже к ftp не могу подключится.

Comment: @Альберт, ну да, потому что ты поменял права для ВСЕХ файлов в системе. И на свои и на системные. Ты бы ещё после "format c:" жаловался, что винда слетела. A-K привёл путь в качестве примера, а ты бездумно поправил и выполнил.

Comment: Теперь вытаскивай файлы, конфиги и переставляй ОС.

Comment: Блин весь день убил на это. Все работает, но эти права. Настраивал со стороны пользователя и для папок и файлов, но все ровно ничего не могу делать через FileZilla. Выводит при попытке создания папки: 550 Create directory operation failed.