# Как настроить уровни доступа для пользователей?

Tags: linux, ssh, администрирование, sftp

Требуется создать пользователя с его домашним каталогом в `/home` при том, что бы он не мог видеть командой `ls` каталоги других пользователей и они ему были не доступны. Так же требуется создать группы пользователей, которым будут доступны только определенные каталоги среди других каталогов и они не могут подниматься на уровень выше. Вся работа будет осуществляться с помощью SFTP.

С администрированием на Linux знаком плохо, надеюсь на помощь. Заранее благодарю)

Comment: chroot jail https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-sftp-user-home-directories-using-chroot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> что бы он не мог видеть командой ls каталоги других пользователей и
>   они ему были не доступны.

Ваши пожелания противоречивы. Каталоги всех пользователей (по умолчанию) создаются в каталоге */home/* Что бы новый пользователь их (эти каталоги) не видел, нужно закрыть ему доступ в каталог */home/*. Но тогда он не увидит даже собственный каталог.

Если же Вы имеете в виду **содержимое** чужих каталогов, то оно и так, по умолчанию, чужому пользователю недоступно.

Вопрос о группе пользователей, которая имеет доступ к некоторому набору каталогов, несколько сложнее. Для этого надо:

1. Создать группу.  Команда  groupadd.
2. Добавить нужных пользователей в новую группу, путём редактирования файла */etc/group*
3. Для всех желаемых каталогов выполнить команду установки группы владельца - chown -R <пользователь>:<новая группа> <каталог>

Ключ -R надо использовать обязательно, т.к. смена собственника должна выполнится и для содержимого каталогов.

Comment: Про /home написано верно, однако я видел разных провайдеров: у одних можно было посмотреть, кто с тобой сосед по хостинку (узнать их id клиента) и сколько их вообще; у других такой возможности не было. Не узнавал, как делается.

Comment: А насчёт групп у меня вот какое замечание. В принципе согласен с написаным, но. Есть стандарные права на файлы (0755) и на папки (0644), которые прописаны во всех букварях. Так вот эти права будут шире -- на группу. Во-первых, будут ругаться автоматические сканнеры безопасности; во-вторых могут ругаться установщики ПО; в-третьих, может ругаться отдел безопасности, если он у вас в конторе предусмотрен. Зависит от степени адекватности сотрудника: может будет вам тыкать "вон везде в сети вот так рекомендуют, почему это у тебя не так?", может свалит все грехи на вас... как фишка ляжет.

Comment: Топикстартеру. Конкретные команды по установки прав на папки и файлы я уже описывал, можно [тут посмотреть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543476/213987) пример.

Comment: @A K **я видел разных провайдеров** - не понял. Провайдеров - чего ?  Или Вы имеете в виду домашние папки виртуальных  web-серверов на на сервере провайдера?

Comment: @A K **Есть стандарные права на файлы (0755) и на папки (0644), которые прописаны во всех букварях** - я хотел бы взглянуть хотя бы на один такой "букварь". Прописывать права 0755 на файл aaaa.txt было бы довольно странно...

Comment: @A K **эти права будут шире -- на группу. Во-первых, будут ругаться автоматические сканеры безопасности** - сдаётся мне, что мы с Вами говорим о каких-то совершенно разных ОС... В Linux (любом!!!) сразу после установки системы, существует целая куча разных групп и практически все папки и файлы содержат триаду битов группы, в правах доступа, в которой хотя бы один бит - не нулевой. Зайдите в корень и выполните "ls -l" - увидите своими глазами.