# Безопасность директории и публичные права на запись и выполнение

Tags: php, javascript, сервер, безопасность, права

JavaScript-файл методом `post` отсылает в `handler_dir/handler.php` строку `base64`-представление бинарного файла с изображением.
Обработчик `handler.php` получает base64-строку, записывает её в созданный им файл и копирует этот файл во временную директорию:

```
$str = $_POST['base64'];
$img = "some_name.jpg";
file_put_contents($img, base64_decode($str));
rename($img, $temp_dir . $img);
```

Методом проб выяснилось, что это решение работает только в том случае, когда для директории обработчика `handler_dir` выставлены **публичные права на запись и выполнение**.

Насколько я понимаю, это очень и очень небезопасно (несмотря на то, что в самом файле `handler.php` происходит проверка авторизации, а в директорию `handler_dir` запрещен доступ на уровне `.htaccess`).

Прошу совета, правильно ли я понимаю, что существующее решение уязвимо в плане безопасности? Существуют ли способы исключить (на любом уровне) загрузку и выполнение вредоносного кода в директории `handler_dir`?

Comment: Что в `$img`? Почему не сохранять файл сразу в `$temp_dir . $img`?

Comment: `$img` - это выбранное имя файла. За идею писать сразу в `$temp_dir` большое спасибо, но разве возможно объединить в конструкцию вроде такой: `file_put_contents($img, $temp_dir . $img, base64_decode($str));` ?

Comment: `но разве возможно` - а кто помешает?

Comment: да, спасибо, так удалось избежать публичных прав на запись для `handler_dir` - `file_put_contents($temp_dir . $img, base64_decode($str));` Осталась проблемная `$temp_dir`, с ней придется разбираться отдельно пользуясь рекомендациями @A K.

Comment: А, вот ещё что гуглить по вашему вопросу о том, чтобы оставить только index.php в веб-каталоге: "единая точка входа", [сегодня попалось в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/756701/213987)

Comment: единая точка входа есть и работает. Правда, я пока не совсем представляю, как инклюдить вынесенный за пределы корня сайта скрипт, а затем обращаться к нему посредством ajax, ведь к тому времени php-скрипт уже прекратит свою работу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как только вы открываете пользователям возможность загружать на сайт какие-то файлы — вы сразу самолично создаёте огромную дыру в безопасности сайта. Это ещё один дополнительный вектор атаки на сайт.

Да, хороший разработчик тут же начинает закрывать эту дыру какими-то действиями, многие из них будут весьма действенными — но до конца закрыть её будет можно лишь теоретически — отняв саму возможность загружать.

Чем плохо ваше решение? Тем, что загрузчик лежит в том же самом каталоге, что и загружаемые файлы. Зачем? Современные практики вообще доходят до того, что на сайте остаётся лишь один index.php, а остальной движок лежит выше уровня www_root. Вам нужно создать отдельную папку `upload` только под загруженные файлы. Отделяйте код от контента — это хорошо как с точки зрения хороших практик программирования, так и помогает с точки зрения безопасности.

Непонятно, почему вы пишете, что "решение работает только в том случае, когда для директории обработчика handler_dir выставлены публичные права на запись и выполнение". Вполне достаточно, чтобы PHP-скрипты имели owner'ом пользователя apache (ну или от кого у вас запускается веб-сервер?) и имели права 0644 (и, при условии включенного SELinux достаточно иметь контекст httpd_sys_content_t).

А вот на папку `upload`, куда вы хотите сохранять картинки, нужно, чтобы owner был apache, права на каталог 0755 и SELinux контекст httpd_sys_rw_content_t.

Что можно порекомендовать на практике для улучшения безопасности?

[В этой статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/148999/) собраны хорошие практики, посмотрите весь чеклист из рекомендованного вопроса [PHP image upload security check list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166762/php-image-upload-security-check-list).

Раз вы загружаете картинки — обратите внимание вот на какой способ защиты. Возьмите и сожмите картинку при помощи GD или ImageMagic на 99% — визуально картинка останется такой же (ну, если это не совсем крохотная картинка, а достаточно крупная), а зловредный код такую трансформацию не переживёт, как бы он не был представлен (приклеен после картинки или внедрён в неё).

> Подскажите, где можно прочитать об изменении уровня относительно
>   www_root?

Видимо что-то типа "Вынесение за пределы корня сайта"? А, вот ещё: "единая точка входа", [сегодня попалось в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/756701/213987). Самое краткое описание это "В идеале, чтобы система была спроектирована так, что в public_html будет лежать только index.php, внутри которого единственное подключение файлика, не лежащего в public_html", в качестве примера движка - посмотрите Laravel

Comment: перечитав вопрос не уверен, что загрузчик лежит там же -- если что вырежу потом из ответа или уточню, что имелось ввиду. По крайней мере, у меня на файле загрузчика нет никаких прав, кроме "можно читать пользователю из-под которого запущен веб-сервер" и в SELinux выставлены права как httpd_sys_content_t (а на директорию upload -- как httpd_sys_rw_content_t  -- подробнее почитать в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/753509/213987))

Comment: как таковой файл не загружается, на вход `handler.php` поступает base64-строка. И лишь после этого созданный `handler.php`-ом файл изображения копируется во временную директорию `$temp_dir`.  Но в любом случае мне самому не нравятся права, которые я установил для `$temp_dir` и директории обработчика `handler_dir`. Подскажите, где можно прочитать об изменении уровня относительно www_root? Есть доступный `how-to`, или хотя бы общепринятое название решения для поиска в гугле?

Comment: Хм. Видимо что-то типа "Вынесение за пределы корня сайта"? Самое краткое описание это "В идеале, чтобы система была спроектирована так, что в public_html будет лежать только index.php, внутри которого единственное подключение файлика, не лежащего в public_html", в качестве примера движка - посмотрите Laravel

Comment: Прошу прощения, что поднимаю этот вопрос: можно ли ограничиться сменой владельца для папки загрузки изображений на apache без того, чтобы конфигурировать SELinux и контекст?

Comment: @118_64 Конечно можно. И работать будет. SELinux -- это уже вишенка на торте безопасности.